# Rails: is it possible to update a foreign key with a HTTP request (Devise, protect_from_forgery)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am writing a module that restricts users to do operations only on their resources. Say, a landlord can do `GET /tenants/1` only if tenant 1 `belongs_to` him/her.

In the update action of the tenants controller I have the following block of code

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @tenant.update_attributes(params[:tenant])
    format.html { redirect_to @tenant, notice: 'Tenant was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render json: @tenant }
  # else ...
end
```

Is it possible for a `landlord` to update the foreign key on his `tenant`, so that the `tenant`'s record potentially moves to some other `landlord`'s account? I use Devise for authentication with `protect_from_forgery` in the application controller. I can extract the `authenticity_token` from a HTML page source in a browser, but the cURL request with that token fails -- WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

Is there a way to fake a foreign key on a record with an HTTP request? Do I need to check foreign keys passed in the params hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to allow this, you should use strong parameters.

In your controller:

```
def tenant_params
   params.require(:tenant).permit(:name, :address ... ) # make sure  :landlord_id is not there
end
```

And in your update action:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @tenant.update_attributes(tenant_params)
    ...
```

This way, even in the unlikely scenario that someone successfully tricks the user to visit a page so elaborate that will actually be able to bypass the csrf token and send a landlord_id parameter to the update action, this parameter will be ignored because it is explicitly not permitted.

There is another method, for example if your list of fields is too long to handle or for any other reasons of your own, instead of using strong parameters, you can just remove a parameter from the post string:

In your update action:

```
params[:tenant].except!(:landlord_id) if !params[:tenant][:landlord_id].nil? #don't forget to use the "bang" (!)
respond_to do |format|
    if @tenant.update_attributes(params[:tenant])
    ....
```

Comment: You might give it a positive vote then, or chose it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've chosen this as an answer, but I can't upvote given my low profile. Cheers!